Auto forwarding messages from telegram to whatsapp
I'm looking for a way to auto forward messages from a telegram group to a whatsapp group. So far I found only how to auto forward messages amongst telegram groups and channels.

Is your question actually programming-related? This is not a support forum - [ask]

@DarkBee yes, I saw that there are bots implemented by using python, google apps script, so I'm looking for a solution that involves a programming language.

So what have you tried yourself? Where are you stuck?

@lu4t why did you delete your answer? I'm trying to follow it, it seems very promising.

The answer provided was a link-only answer to a video, he/she was also affiliated with, which was deleted by moderation because link-only answers are not good answers

@lu4t maybe it could be useful to write your previous answer as a comment.
